# Why does the timer have to go first in a dripper system head assembly?

Tags: drip-system

In order for my timers valves to open the water pressure must be lowered.  So my head assembly order is: hose bib, backflow preventer, pressure regulator, hose adapter, 6' hose, timer, dripper system.  This allows the valves on the timer to open properly.  My question is, why do all of the head assembly instructions have the timer first?  When I place my timer first the valves will not open.  What am I missing?

Comment: Since all systems vary and you do not mentions the brand/model system purchased, perhaps the best help would be achieved by contacting the specific manufacturer of your gear? Most companies offer excellent online and even freephone after-care for their specific products which will greatly exceed anything non-specific we could offer you.